# Unable to change css from external css

Tags: html, css, flask

i have been trying to change the css for my html using external style sheet but nothing changes when i edit my main.css . The css of the webpage uses the initial css when i first added main.css but after that i cannot make any changes.

These are my codes for referencing:

```
<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/main.css')}}" />
</head>
```

These are my codes for main.css:

```
html,
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin:0px;
}

header {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #837373;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

hr {
    width: 100%;
    height:1px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: darkblue;
    border: 0 none;
}

input[type=text] {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    background-color: #ddd;
    outline: none;
}

.top-container {
    background: #d1d1d1;
    padding:5px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #0f0f0f;
}

.bottom-container {
    background: black;
    padding:5px;
    border-top:2px solid #0f0f0f;
    /* position:absolute; */
    bottom:0;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.error-message {
    color :red;
}
```

So, for example my webpage now shows the css styling for the main.css shown above but now i cant make any changes for e.g when i change background to red it does not change. I think its something to do with static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the filename does not change, your browser keeps thinking that it is the same file, thus loading the first downloaded file from cache and using that.

Making the browser download and use the new file (even though it has a similar name) is called [Cache Busting](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/).
When using an Apache-server, I recommend using [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html), but keep in mind that using many `.htaccess`-files is slowing down the server drastically, so it is best to configure such rewrites in your `httpd.conf`-file directly.